# Detect SQLServer features from ADO.net

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have an app that creates SQL tables and enables DATA_COMPRESSION=Page. However, that feature is only available when the Enterprise version of SQLServer is being used. There are times when I would like to use this same code on, for example,  a SQLLocalDB SKU. For these cases I would like to skip the DATA_COMPRESSION setting because it is not supported and throws an error.

Is it possible for me to detect if this feature is available, (or next best), detect that SQLLocalDB is being used?

I'm using ADO.net to connect to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open an `SqlConnection` to database and check [ServerVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.serverversion(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // use con.ServerVersion
}
```

If you want to know more details you can query for properties by using [SERVERPROPERTY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx)

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')
```

Or

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')
```

> Database Engine edition of the instance of SQL Server installed on the
>   server.
>
> 1 = Personal or Desktop Engine (Not available in SQL Server 2005 and
>   later versions.)
>
> 2 = Standard (This is returned for Standard, Web, and Business
>   Intelligence.)
>
> 3 = Enterprise (This is returned for Evaluation, Developer, and both
>   Enterprise editions.)
>
> 4 = Express (This is returned for Express, Express with Tools and
>   Express with Advanced Services)
>
> 5 = SQL Database
>
> 6 - SQL Data Warehouse
>
> Base data type: int